# text data put into PQ heapsort

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I am trying to input data from a text file into a dynamic array and then sort it using PQ Heap sort 
the program works with regular 1-d array but when using text file it does not work: here the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void swapData(int&, int& );

class PQHeapSort{ 
public:
    PQHeapSort(int DataSize) : NIndex(0) { PQ = new int[DataSize];}
    ~PQHeapSort() {delete[] PQ; }
    void InsertData(int);
    int RemoveData();

    void DisplayData();
    void BubbleDown(int*, int, int);
    void BubbleUp (int*, int);

private:
       int *PQ;
       int NIndex;
};

void PQHeapSort::BubbleUp(int a[], int bindex){
    while (bindex>1 && a[bindex] < a[bindex/2]){
       if(a[bindex] < a[bindex/2]){
            swapData(a[bindex], a[bindex/2]);}
            bindex= bindex/2;

    }
}

void PQHeapSort::BubbleDown(int a[], int b, int c){
    while (2*b <= c){
        int child = 2*b;
        if(child<c && a[child]>a[child+1]){
            child++;
        }
        if (a[b]>a[child]) {
            swapData(a[b], a[child]);
            b = child;
        }
        else return;
    }
}

void PQHeapSort::InsertData(int item){
        PQ[++NIndex] = item;
       BubbleUp(PQ, NIndex);

}

int PQHeapSort:: RemoveData(){

        swapData(PQ[NIndex], PQ[1]);
        BubbleDown(PQ, 1, NIndex-1);
        return PQ[NIndex--];


}

void PQHeapSort::DisplayData(){
    for(int i = 1; i<=NIndex; i++){
        cout<<PQ[i]<<" ";


    }

}


void swapData(int &a, int &b){
    int tempData = b;
    b = a;
    a = tempData;

}

int main()
{
    int ArraySize = 0;
    string inputFile;

    ifstream inFile;

    cout << "Please enter the name of the input file: ";
    cin >> inputFile;
    inFile.open(inputFile.c_str());

    int data;
    while(inFile>>data){
        ArraySize++;

    }
    int *TextData = 0 TextData = new int[ArraySize];

    for(int i=0; i<ArraySize; i++){
        inFile>>TextData[i];
        PQHeapSort *q = new PQHeapSort(ArraySize-1);
        q->InsertData(TextData[i]);
        q->DisplayData();
        cout<<"min data remove"<< q->RemoveData()<<endl;
        q->DisplayData();

    }








    return 0;
}
```

how would you convert this into Java

Comment: `it does not work:` what doesn't work?

Comment: Start by properly reading the file. You seek to the end counting integers, then never rewind for your main loader loop, which itself base a *blatant* memory leak, each iteration leaking a new `PQHeapSort` object into the ether.

Comment: what does not work is that it does not print out the correct data